# How to rename a Datastore entity field but be able to retrieve records via old and new property names?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have an entity

```
class Foo {
  public String bar;
}
```

I want to rename "bar" to "somethingElse". And was planning on using Objectify's @AlsoLoad annotation to achieve that (I am already using Objectify for persistence). So something like:

```
class Foo {
  @AlsoLoad("bar")
  public String somethingElse;
}
```

But any queries of the form:

```
final Query<Foo> query = OfyService.ofy().load().type(Foo.class)
    .filter("somethingElse", "someValue");
```

Only retrieve entities that have been saved since the rename. Any older entities are ignored.

What is best practice for renaming entity fields so that I can have a single query that will return all records?

Comment: This may help as a reference - cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: I'm not an objectify user, the answer is generic, so you'd have to adapt it to objectify specifics.

In general you want to avoid using both `bar` and `somethingElse` for extended periods of time, primarily because finding matching entities translates into an `OR` type of query - `.filter("bar", "someValue")` **OR** `.filter("somethingElse", "someValue")`, which is fundamentally unsupported by the datastore. From [Restrictions on queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#restrictions_on_queries):

> The `NOT`, `OR`, and `!=` operators are not natively supported,
>   but some client libraries may add support on top of Cloud Datastore.

This means that, at best, you'd have to jump through hoops to make something like this work, see, for example, [Google Datastore combine (union) multiple sets of entity results to achieve OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437166/google-datastore-combine-union-multiple-sets-of-entity-results-to-achieve-or-c/47438039#47438039)

My suggestion is to perform a one-off migration and be done with it. It would contain the following steps:

- most likely you'll have to have *both* properties configured/alive during the migration, so don't just rename `bar`, instead add `somethingElse` and don't immediately delete `bar`
- in all places where you update the `bar` property also update `somethingElse` accordingly
- add logic to query for all entities which have `bar` but don't have `somethingElse` and re-write them so they also have `somethingElse`. After this step completes all the entities should have a `somethingElse` mirroring `bar`
- in all non-query places where you read `bar`'s value switch to reading `somethingElse` instead
- check that all indexes containing `somethingElse` are serving, then switch your queries from `bar` to `somethingElse`. With this the actual migration is complete and you can execute the cleanup steps below
- drop writing the `bar` property
- perform queries for all entitites having a `bar` property and re-write them without `bar`. Note that this could be more expensive than actually leaving these entities alone
- drop `bar` from your models and indexes (if applicable to your client library), but only if you deleted the property from all your entities in the previous step

A migration following this approach can be performed slowly as it doesn't require complete service shutdown, it can be done *live*.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I had come to the same conclusion.